# Remove tabs in email body due to tabs in Python code

Tags: python

I have the following code that sends email. It renders correctly except it displays the message with tabs. This section of code is tabbed correctly in the logic, it looks like it's honoring the tab in the codebase and passing it through the email library.

```
if rc != 0:
    ...
    email_body = """
    Module: %s
    Installed: %s
    Required: %s
    """ %(module, installed_version, required_version)
    ...
```

## Output

```
myhost.localdomain
    Module: XYZ
    Installed: None
    Required: ABC123
```

Comment: Module, Installed and Required should line up under the hostname.

Comment: It is doing exactly what you said. Remove the tabs in front of it and you'll be good. Or if that looks ugly, manually put `\n`s in your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [MIMEText](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.mime.html) to form email_body:

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


# ...
email_body = """
Module: %s
Installed: %s
Required: %s
""" %(module, installed_version, required_version)

email_body = MIMEText(email_body)
# ...
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Just don't put leading tabs in the heredoc strings:

```
if rc != 0:
    ...
    # trailing slash: omit linebreak in string
    email_body = """\
Module: %s
Installed: %s
Required: %s""" %(module, installed_version, required_version)
    ...
```

Comment: Ah, ok I thought I tried that and it broke my code. I think I was missing the `\`

Comment: The next line needs to start in the same indent level as `email_body = """`. Maybe you dedented an unrelated line?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [`textwrap.dedent(text)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent)

> Remove any common leading whitespace from every line in text.

```
>>> # end first line with \ to avoid the empty line!
>>> print textwrap.dedent("""\                                      
...     Module: %s                                                 
...     Installed: %s                                              
...     Required: %s                                               
...     """ %('a', 'b', 'c'))
Module: a
Installed: b
Required: c

>>>
```

You can also write your string as:

```
>>> print("Module: %s\n"                                                 
...       "Installed: %s\n"                                              
...       "Required: %s"                                               
...       %('a', 'b', 'c'))
Module: a
Installed: b
Required: c

>>>
```